# Regex matching just

Tags: regex

Dumb beginner style question but I've wrestled with this for a while now, searches result is not quite what I'm after so I'm asking you guys instead!

Given the text below I only want to extract the Id associated with the bottom line (ie 100)

```
<test viewId=101&somemoreStuff=999>Dont match this</test>
<test viewId=100&somemoreStuff=111>Match this</test>
```

so I started with something like this (regular expression):

```
/viewId=(.+?)&
```

This captures the Id for the first line but I'm after the Id of the second line so I need to include the string "Match this" to distinguish between the two, something like this (pseudo code):

```
/viewId=(.+?)&[ignore this section]>Match this<
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
viewId=(.+?)&[^>]*>Match this<
```

You can try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/46

Answer (score 1):

Postive look aheads will be helpfull

```
viewId=(.+?)(?=&.*Match this)
```

[**Regex Example**](http://regex101.com/r/pU2sD3/1)

- `(?=&.*Match this)` postive look ahead. Asserts that the `viewId` is followed by `Match this`